# Unable to parse 1040 for the year 2020

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I am encountering issues while attempting to parse the 1040 form for the year 2020 using a dummy data PDF file. Got this exception Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="Unable to find a document of type: '1040_' (excluding {1040_2020}).")

But I am able to successfully parse the 1040 form for the year 2018. Is there anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For the Document AI [1040 Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_1040-parser), you'll need to use processor version [`pretrained-1040-v2.0-2022-08-24` to process 2020 and 2021 form versions](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_1040-parser:%7E:text=2020%20(pretrained%2D1040%2Dv2.0%2D2022%2D08%2D24%20version%20only)).

You can accomplish this by setting that version as the default processor version or by sending a specific processor version in the request body.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/manage-processor-versions

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request